# Optional params in angularjs $resouce method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

my case is, i want angularjs auto remove parameters defined in method :

My definition :

```
var service = $resource(apiConstant.baseUrl + '/website/:action', {port : ':8080'}, {
        save: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                action: 'save', id: '@id', name: '@name', description: '@description',
                ownerId: '@ownerId', checked: '@checked'
            }
        }
    });
```

When i call service.save({id :3}), the actual URL generated is :

```
website/save?checked=undefined&description=undefined&id=3&name=undefined&ownerId=undefined
```

How can i tell angularjs auto remove those parameter not specified ?

I'm just want like this  :

```
website/save?id=3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you need to define in the `params` array would be `action:'save'` and that's it.

```
params: {
            action: 'save'
 }
```

Then when we do save({id:3}) it would only call the desired url.

`params` array is used to bind parameters in url not in querystring. Also the @id syntax is used to map the parameter from the payload (object).